# Libgdx NESTED ShapeRenderer not drawing lines

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

In the code below I retrieve an arraylist of vertices (I've debugged and they are in fact there) and then attempt to render them in this nest loop arrangement which is hosted in the render method. For some reason, the ShapeRenderer cannot connect all the lines if this is nested? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Nothing is being drawn to the screen; I get no errors.

```
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    for(int i = 0;i<tmpBodies.size;i++)
    {   
        if(tmpBodies.get(i).getType().equals(BodyType.DynamicBody) && 
           !tmpBodies.get(i).equals(car.getChassis()) &&
           !tmpBodies.get(i).equals(car.rightWheel)&& 
           !tmpBodies.get(i).equals(car.leftWheel)&& 
           !tmpBodies.get(i).equals(terrain))  // tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList().get(0).getShape().equals(Type.Chain)
        {
            ChainShape tempShape = new ChainShape();
            ArrayList<Vector2> bodyPoints = new ArrayList<Vector2>();

            tempShape = (ChainShape)tmpBodies.get(i).getFixtureList()
                                    .get(0).getShape();

            for(int q=0; q<tempShape.getVertexCount(); q++)
            {
                Vector2 linePoints = new Vector2();

                tempShape.getVertex(q, linePoints);

                Vector2 newLinePoints = tmpBodies.get(i).getWorldPoint(linePoints);
                bodyPoints.add(newLinePoints);
            }

            for(int z=0; z<tempShape.getVertexCount()-1; z++)
            {
                shapeRenderer.setColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
                shapeRenderer.line(bodyPoints.get(z).x,
                                   bodyPoints.get(z).y,
                                   bodyPoints.get(z+1).x,
                                   bodyPoints.get(z+1).y);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I highly suggest storing `tmpBodies.get(i)` in a local variable, so you don't waste time receiving it from the list every time you need it (which seems to be quite a bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not if I explain well, that is, possible? you need use another matrix4, if using box2d eg units for PPM.

`shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);`

change for example:

```
testMatrix4 Matrix4; //<-- Variable Class.
```

//in Your code

```
//Other Code

//batch or Camera Matrix

testMatrix4 = batch.getProyectionMatrix().cpy()
                .scale(YOUR_PPM_X, YOUR_PPM_Y, 0);

shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(testMatrix4);

//Other Code
```

I never did something like this, but if it does not work, notify me, that I erase.

Comment: I have other things that are being rendered by the shaperenderer so not everything is not being renderer; just these lines. i already have ppm set up in the camera itself.